# Where to find the installer for SQL Server Native Client 11.0.7462?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, native-client

I would like the exact version mentioned since my application does not support the 11.0.5058 version of the SQL Server Native Client (sqlncli).

Comment: Can you also let me know the version of SQL Server I guess it is SQL Server 2012 ?

Comment: Yes I am using 2012

Comment: Did you try to download [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057116/security-update-for-vulnerabilities-in-sql-server) patch and only update native client (ignore other components if you do not want to update everything).  [These](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/installing-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-2017) instructions might help.

Comment: Thank you It is working

Comment: I put my comment as an answer so others can get benefited. It that answered your question please mark it.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps.

1. Download patch [Description of the security update for SQL Server 2012 SP4 GDR: January 12, 2018](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057116/security-update-for-vulnerabilities-in-sql-server) which is version 11.0.7464.
2. Only update native client (ignore other component) following [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/installing-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-2017) instructions.